# PHP remove final separator within Loop

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, while-loop

On the last part, I'm just trying to remove the last pound (#) separator.
I know it's a simple IF statement but I can't figure it out. Thx in advance

```
<?php
    reset($values);
    while($value = current($values)) 
    {
        echo $value . " # ";
        next($values);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I would store the `$values` in an array, then `implode()` with `#` as the glue.

Comment: sorry, i should've been more specific. they're already stored in an array.. i didn't include the code. it's just to output all the values with the pound operator but remove the last pound sign. something like:

44 # 234 # 254# 365 # 734

Comment: See my edit. See if that works. Knowing that the `#` is already in there makes a difference. Now I can see why you are saying `if/else` is probably required.

Comment: did you try this `echo implode(" # ", $values)` instead of loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, I would store in an array then implode() the stored array.

```
<?php
    reset($values);
    while($value = current($values)) {
            // Remove # here, just store values
            $array[] = $value;
            next($values);
        }
    // Check that values have been stored
    if(isset($array) && !empty($array))
        // Implode with the # character
        echo implode("#",$array);
    ?>
```

**EDIT:**

Since the `#` is already stored in your values, you could use `count()` and `str_replace()`:

```
<?php
    // Dummy array maker
    for($a=1;$a<=10;$a++)
        $values[]   =   $a.'#';

    // Count how many are in array
    $count = count($values);
    reset($values);
    $i = 1;
    while($value = current($values)) {
            // If the count is equal to the $i, remove #
            echo ($i == $count)? str_replace("#","",$value) : $value;
            next($values);
            $i++;
        }
    ?>
```

**Gives you:**

```
1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9#10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0;$i<=(count($values)-1);$i++) {
        $str = $values[$i];
        $total =count($values)-1;
           if((count($values)-1) == $i){
            echo $str =$str.'';
        }else{
            echo $str =$str.'#';
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.